# Firefox or Firefox tabs die when you run it from terminal and then kill said terminal

Tags: shell-script

I'm making this really nice script that is supposed to make my life a little bit easier by opening apps for me and I've ran into an issue with launching Firefox (or any similar browser really; same happens with Chromium as well).

Here's what my scripts do: I have initial script that launches a terminal window and runs my script in said window. That script is being launched through XFCE's sessions and startup (in bash, in a new xfce-terminal window) and works fine.

Now my second script looks like this:

```bash
foo=string
grep ';;' ~/sh.sh
read foo
#firefox &>/dev/null &
#disown

for (( i=0; i<${#foo}; i++ )); do
    case ${foo:$i:1} in
        0)  nohup mypaint &>/dev/null & ;;
        1)  exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator  ;;
        2)  gtk-launch firefox.desktop  ;;
        3)  ~/shsh/lutris.sh    ;;
        4)  nohup /usr/lib/chromium/chromium &>/dev/null &  ;;
        5)  nohup mypaint &>/dev/null &     ;;
        6)  nohup steam &>/dev/null &   ;;
    esac
done

sleep 5 && kill -1 $PPID
```

And the problem is: when I launch firefox through this script depending on the method I'm trying to use to detach firefox process from shell one of the two things happen: either firefox is being closed with terminal window or terminal window closes with tabs crashing (and addblock no longer working as well).

Here's the methods I've used so far:

- multiple different combinations of `nohup`, `&>/dev/null &` and `disown`
- `gtk-launch firefox.desktop &` and `disown`
- `(firefox &)` and `disown` (this one works really well if you just type it in but doesn't work the same way in script)

And interestingly enough `firefox` does become a child of the `init` process but still dies, or tabs are still crashing, when terminal window is being closed through script.

So at this point it's either Firefox being a bitch or I'm missing a puzzle piece.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found a workaround, which is: `xfce4-terminal --execute nohup firefox`. It opens a new terminal window, executes the command, closes said window for some reason, and if the main shell gets killed by `kill -1`, it doesn't kill firefox -- neither does it crash tabs.

Comment: See also the comments at ChanganAuto's answer and *Bac0n's answer* at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378056/ubuntu-20-04-3-problems-running-firefox-from-terminal/1378057). (It may be more difficult with Gnome than with XFCE.)

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox-esr dont crash, if you do on follow way:

Start the Firefox from terminal or by .sh script:

```
nohup firefox-esr --detach & disown
```

Close your Terminal window by hand or by kill.